# Manipulating datetime formats in pandas for Athena

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-athena

Due to the way Pandas and Athena read datetime formats, I've had to manipulate several columns in order to get the data in a format that works.

Which involves converting a string to a datetime

```
df["serviceStartTimestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["serviceStartTimestamp"])

returning

0   2019-08-07 08:04:43.942000+00:00
1   2019-08-07 08:13:48.397000+00:00
2   2019-08-07 09:02:29.067000+00:00
```

then running this,

```
df["serviceStartTimestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["serviceStartTimestamp"].astype("str").str.split("+", expand=True)[0])

returning

0   2019-08-07 08:04:43.942
1   2019-08-07 08:13:48.397
2   2019-08-07 09:02:29.067
```

If the datetime columns include any further digits they get completed messed up in athena,
but how I'm currently solving it seems inefficient, so I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`.

```
pd.to_datetime(df["serviceStartTimestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Output:

```
0   2019-08-07 08:04:43.942
1   2019-08-07 08:13:48.397
2   2019-08-07 09:02:29.067
```

Comment: that still returns 
```0   2019-08-07 08:04:43.942000+00:00```

Comment: @davo777 see the edit. This MUST work. If not, please post raw `df["serviceStartTimestamp"]` .

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, this works ```df["serviceStartTimestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["serviceStartTimestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')```, just needs a bracket before the .dt